# Circles detection in image on specific location

Tags: c#, python

I am working for a project in this project I have to find circles in an image on ten different location.
I know that i should share some code here also but I am not sucu experienced, I am just a new comer to development.
It will be very great full for you if anyone guide me how to do this task.
Find circle in image on 10 different locations according to x-axis and y-axis in C# or python

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `OpenCV` ?

Another option is [Azure Computer Vision](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/)
It is free as long as you don't have like thousand of users using it.

Comment: Where can i learn this technology? I don't know anything about it.